# Batch issue with FIND command

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to get a test code working so I can make a more complex version of the script for my actual needs, but I'm struggling with the FIND command.

My code:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

>"%~dpn1_b.txt" (
  FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%j in ('find /V /N "" %1') DO (
    SET "currentLine=%%k"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    IF "!currentLine:~0,3!"=="12/" (
      SET string=!currentLine:~0,2!!currentLine:~3,4!
      FIND "%string%" 111.txt > nul
      IF %errorlevel% EQU 0 (SET "currentLine=!currentLine:~0,2!!currentLine:~3!")
    )
    ECHO(!currentline!
    ENDLOCAL
  )
)
```

This is executed by dragging test.txt onto the batch file.

111.txt holds 123456. test.txt has 12/3456 on the first line and 12/4456 on the second line. The script is supposed to remove the slash from the first line but not from the second. Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: General tip: Remove `@echo off` from the top of your file when debugging.

Comment: I forgot to mention the script doesn't abort or anything. It removes both slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the `FOR` loop body, all environment variable expansions using the `%var%` format will be pre-expanded. You still need to use the delayed expansion `!var!` format even for internal variables like `errorlevel`.

```
FOR /F ... (
    ...
    FIND "!string!" 111.txt > nul
    IF !errorlevel! EQU 0 (SET "currentLine=!currentLine:~0,2!!currentLine:~3!")
)
```

As Ryan mentioned, this is clearer if you leave ECHO enabled as you see that with the original code the last two statements in the loop were being pre-expanded:

> FIND "" 111.txt  1>nul
>
> IF 0 EQU 0 (SET "currentLine=!currentLine:~0,2!!currentLine:~3!" )

Answer (score 0):

interesting: you get the line numbers (`%%j`) but then don't use it...

How about:

```
...
if "%%j"=="[1" (
  ...
) else (
  echo %%k
)
...
```

Comment: No - you have missed the point. - Using FIND or FINDSTR to insert the line number, followed by a delimiter, is a standard technique used to preserve empty lines when using FOR /F. The `%%j` value is intentionally ignored, unless you want to manipulate a specific line within the text. The OP does not know which line has the text.

Comment: @dbenham_ " to remove the slash from the first line but not from the second."

Comment: Ahh - I see the source of your confusion. I believe the OP intends the statement to mean that *in this particular case* only the first line should be modified. But the line number could change from instance to instance. It all depends on whether the constructed string for any given line is found within 111.txt.